# Project Euler 14: the output is always zero

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve Project Euler 14 and the output is always zero.

The basic Idea is `n/2` when `n` is even and `3n + 1` when `n` is odd.
Then if `m/2 < n` or `m < n` (where `m/2` or `m` is previous number whose number had already been calculated) give the number of iterations as iterations stored. 
I am storing the iterations of previous numbers.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool ok=true;
unsigned long int p[1000001]; //initialization of array p to store iterations
unsigned long int q[2]={1,1}; // initialization of two element array to store the max sequence number
unsigned long int x=0;

int Colltz(unsigned long int num,unsigned long int count) { // function starts
    unsigned long int j=num;
    p[0]=0; //Initial iterations for 1 and 2
    p[1]=1; // Initial value for 1
    p[2]=2; // Initial val for 3
    while(ok) { // while loop

        if((j%2==0)&&(j/2>num)) { //(to check whether j is available in the array if not it divides it further until j/2<num
            j=j/2;
            ++count;
        }

        if((j%2==0)&&((j/2)<num)) { // since j/2 the arry should contin the number and the collatz vlue is +1
            ++count;
            p[num]=p[j/2]+count;
            ok=false;
            break;
        }

        if ((j%2)!=0) { //if it is odd
            j=3*j+1;
            ++count;
            Colltz(j,count);
        }
        if(j<num) { // if j < num then j is Collatz of j is calculated and added
            p[num]=p[j]+count;
            ok=false;
            break;
        }
        if((p[num]>=q[1])) {
            q[0]=num; // to get the max count
            q[1]=p[num];
        }
    }// end of while loop
    return q[1];
}

int main() {
    unsigned long int i=3;
    unsigned long int j=0;
    int counted=1;

    while(i<6) {
        j=Colltz(i,counted);
        ++i;
    }
    cout<<j;
}
```

So basically my function should take in the number (for which I have initialized `count` to `0`) and then find out whether it is even or odd and if it is even whether it is greater than `n` or less and then follow steps accordingly and if it is odd whether it is less than `n` and calculate accordingly.

Comment: Consult this wiki page, fix appropriately, you will likely get more quality responses.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd like to help you, but I don't understand how you are trying to solve the problem. I tried a standard brute force approach and I was able to get the result in less than a second. https://gist.github.com/moretti/6141287

Comment: your code is a bit of mess (to me) you are re-initializing p[0-2] in function that should be in array declaration/definition and the rest of p is unknown non-handled!!! The meaning and location of ok evades me. and now the most important you set p[num] but never use it to speed up the search you should ad if statement at start of function something like if (p[num]!=0) return p[num] or count=p[num] do not have the will to determine your function interface. also that will works only if you reset the p[] array to zero values first !!! if this does not help add comment and i post code in answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a little bit messed up! Check my solution and see whether that helps :

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned long int Collatz(unsigned long int);

int main()
{
    unsigned long int n,i,bingo;
    int ChainLen=0;
    for(i=1;i<=1000000;i++)
    {

        if((n=Collatz(i)) > ChainLen)
        {
            ChainLen=n;
            bingo=i;
        }

    }
    printf("\n%lu\n",bingo);
    return 0;
}

unsigned long int Collatz(unsigned long int x)
{
    if(x==1)
    return 1;
    if(x%2==0)
    {
        return 1 + Collatz(x/2);
    }
    else
    return 1 + Collatz(x * 3 + 1);
}
```